# Focus a Text composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I need to make a custom text editor composable with some custom behavior and appearance that should be quite different from a `TextField` composable, so I'm starting from a `Text` composable instead.

I encounter two problems: I cannot manage to open the keyboard when clicking on the composable. And don't manage to have the Text get the focus. I believe that the later is the reason to the former.

Here is a simplified version of the composable:

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun FocusText(
    modifier: Modifier,
    text: String
) {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    Text(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier
            .focusable(true)
            .focusModifier()
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .onFocusChanged { it: FocusState ->
                println("xxx onFocusChanged: $it")
            }
            .clickable {
                println("xxx onClick")
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                keyboardController?.show()
            }
    )
}
```

Despite having both `.focusable(true)` and `.focusModifier()` and calling `requestFocus()` in `onClick()`, the composable doesn't get the focus when clicking on it.
Also, the keyboard doesn't get opened.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**`BasicTextField`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#BasicTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush,kotlin.Function1)) instead of a `Text`.
It is basically an `EditText` via hardware or software keyboard, without decoration hint or placeholder. Of course you can add it.

Something like:

```
var value by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("edit text") }

BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it }
)
```